# Why implicit conversion to std::string doesn't work with operator<< being called

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

At first, I used a user-defined convert function to implicitly convert an object to `int` and then inserted it to `cout` with `<<` operator. The program was compiled successfully and printed '0'.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class T {
public:
    operator int () {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    T a;
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I tried to do the same thing except that the object was converted to a `std::string`. The program got a compile error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class T {
public:
    operator string () {
        return "";
    }
};

int main()
{
    T a;
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why implicit conversion doesn't happen on the second case.

Comment: To get the compiler error in the first case as well, use `explicit operator int () { return 0; }`.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question because MCVE has been provided and the question is quite clear now.

Answer (score 9):

> Why implicit conversion doesn't happen on the second case.

Because [`operator<<(std::basic_string)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is a template function,

> ```
> template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
> std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
>     operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, 
>                const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
> ```

That means given `T a; cout << a << endl;`, for it to be called, all the three template parameters need to be deduced. But in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), implicit conversion won't be considered and then deduction fails.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

On the other hand, [`std::basic_ostream::operator<<(int)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is a non-template function; it doesn't have such issues.